# Calling android command from shell script: Not working

Tags: android, shell, osx-mavericks

I am trying to run a script that has an android command inside it. I have set the path of tools and platform-tools in my .bash_profile in my mac.  And i am able to run the android command directly from the shell. But the same fails when i run a script containing android command.
The error i get : android: command not found

```
NAME=$1
PATH=$2
PACKAGE=$3

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3

function create_new_android_project()
{
    android create project -n "$NAME" -t 7 -p "$PATH" -k "$PACKAGE" -a MainActivity
}

create_new_android_project
echo
echo "******** Complete!!!"
```

When i run this script in my mac shell with the command `sh script.sh name path package`, I get an error saying android: command not found.

Comment: show some piece of code

Comment: Edited the question to include the code.

Comment: What does `$ which android` return? I stuck mine in `/opt`, so I receive `/opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android`. `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is `/opt/android-sdk-macosx`, so I export `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools` and `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platfrom-tools` in my `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I tried which android, it returns **/Volumes/Machintosh HD/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android**. And this is exactly what i have written in .bash_profile